# separating map values - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a livesearch ajax, php, mysql and is composed of:

a json resulting from a php

```html
{
"421": {
 "name_1": "First name 1",
 "name_2": "Last name 1",
 "locality": "Locality 1"
 },
"866": {
 "name_1": "First name 2",
 "name_2": "Last name 2",
 "locality": "Locality 2"
 },
.....

}
```

and this html code:

```html
<input type="text" name="customer" id="customer" class="form-control input-lg" autocomplete="off" />
    <input type="text" id="id_customer" >
<div id="locality" ></div>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#customer').typeahead({
            source: function(query, result)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    url:"customer_json_inc.php",
                    method:"POST",
                    data:{query:query},
                    dataType:"json",
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        result($.map(data, function(elem, index){
                            $('#id_customer').val(index);
                            console.log(index);
                            return elem.name_1;
                        }));
                    }
                })
            }
        });

    });
</script>
```

A demo version can be viewed [here](http://webslesson.info/2017/04/dynamic-autocomplete-search-using-bootstrap-typeahead-with-php-ajax.html)

I do not succeed in taking one of the indexes (ex: 421, 866, ...) depending on what is selected in `id="customer"` input and entering it in input `id="id_customer"`, so try for div- `id="locality"`.

In my code in result in the code line: `$('# id_customer').Val(index);` inserts the last index identified at the first letter entered, while I want to insert the index of the selected customer into the input.

Thank you!

Comment: not clear what exactly you want to do

Comment: when I search for a name in #customer from json 'name_1' and choose 'First name 1' in input #id_customer to insert index 421